# Question title text in tour looks like a link

Tags: discussion, design, tour

The question title text in [tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour) looks like a link when you hover over it, but it isn't actually one:

> [image]

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is by design. In the tour, it doesn't function, but clearly tells that in the real question it would be a link, because the text colour changes to a bit lighter on hover - that's default for "ordinary" links, as I know.

There is no point to make it a real link; that's just an example. In fact, even votes and favourites don't match, and in the real question, another answer is accepted.

Again, that's just an example, to let a new user understand how the things work - if you make it a link, then all the inconsistencies I mentioned would just confuse new users.

(And, just while we are there: I'd make the user names also look like links in the example question)